# How do you factor this polynomial?

Tags: group-theory

$$x^4+x^3+1 \in \mathbb Z_{2}$$

**Attempt:**

There are no linear factors, because substituting $0$ and $1$ in the place of $x$, the polynomial is not reducible.

We can't apply the freshman's dream, because the polynom is not a square.

Comment: The polynomial has no linear factor. The irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ also doesn't divide it. Conclusion?

Comment: What does this mean? *"The irreducible polynomial of degree 2 also doesn't divide it"*

Comment: How many irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ are there in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no linear factor, then there is no cubic factor. (Why?) Thus, the only way it may be factored is as a product of quadratics. In particular, the quadratics must be irreducible. (Why?) But there is only one irreducible quadratic in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ (why?) so if it were a product of quadratics, it would be a square, which it is not (due to the $x^3$ term). Thus, it cannot be factored into lower degree polynomials. (That is, you're done!)

Comment: This is not clear to me: *In particular, the quadratics must be irreducible*. Anyway is the irreducible $x^2+x+1$?

Comment: Yes, the irreducible quadratic is $x^2+x+1.$ What does it mean for a quadratic to be reducible?

Comment: @Deleted A factor of a factor is…

Comment: It *should* be reducible if $p(x)=0$ for at least one x. (Anyway, the previous answer with all the polynoms was more comprensible imho).

Comment: @Deleted: If $p$ is a quadratic polynomial such that $p(x)=0$ for at least one $x,$ what does that tell you about the factors of $p$?

Comment: I don't know, what should it tell to me about his factors?

Comment: Well, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $p(a)=0,$ then what is a factor of $p(x)$?

Comment: $x-a$ should be a factor, isn't it?

Comment: @Deleted: Exactly! Thus, a reducible quadratic (or any reducible polynomial of degree greater than $1$) has at least one linear factor. Why does this mean that $x^4+x^3+1$ cannot have any reducible quadratic factors, then?

Comment: Maybe that the linear factor of the quadratic polynom would (also) be factor of the main polynom $x^4+x^3+1$?

Comment: And since we've already concluded that $x^4+x^3+1$ has no linear factors, then it therefore has no reducible quadratic factors. Does it all make sense now, or are there still parts you don't follow?

Comment: A perfect teacher.

Comment: Well, hardly perfect, but one does what one can. ;-) Glad I could help.

Comment: @CameronBuie the same exercise asks to find an element $\in E:=Z_{2}/(x^4+x^3+1)$ which has multiplicative period of 15. How could I find it?

Answer (score 0):

If $\,g\,$ had an irred. quadratic factor $f$ then in $\,\Bbb Z_2[x]/f \cong \Bbb F_4,\ $ $x\ne 0\,\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{x^3 = 1}$ by Lagrange, thus $\,\color{#0a0}{x^4=x},\,$ hence
$\, f\mid g\,\Rightarrow\, 0 = g = \color{#0a0}{x^4} + \color{#c00}{x^3} + 1 = \color{#0a0}x+\color{#c00}1+1 = x,\, $ contradiction.