# Modular inverse by Euler's theorem for Gaussian integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, totient-function, gaussian-integers

To compute the multiplicative inverse modulo a prime one can use extended GCD or Euler's theorem:

$$x^{-1} = x^{p-2} \mod p$$

Is there similar formula for x being a Gaussian integer? I'm asking because

$$-i^{3-2} \mod 3 = -i$$

but Mathematica says:

```
PowerMod[-i, -1, 3] = i
```

Comment: If your are asking if there is an analog of little Fermat in a finite field $\,\Bbb Z[i]/p\,$ then the answer is yes (hint: apply Lagrange's theorem to the multiplicative group). But it's usually more efficient to use the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: For an example of an application of Lagrange in a finite field see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/650179/242) and  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3828825/242) (alas, it seem Lagrange gets no respect here - as elegant as his ideas may be....)

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm asking how to compute multiplicative inverse of a Gaussian integer without extended GCD (i.e. with Euler's theorem). In other words, why can't I simply use the the formula when imaginary part of $x$ is not zero.